# Setting up a eclipse project for learning gcc

Tags: eclipse, gcc

I cloned git repository for gcc from github.com.
Now I want to navigate the code from eclipse. I have indigo eclipse in windows.
How to setup the project(like setting the include paths), so that issues like:
"GC_NOT_ALPHA not resolved" doesnot come up.

Comment: You can just open the files in a normal editor and the Makefile that's included should build it for you

Comment: The thing is that I want to navigate code in eclipse easily so that when I look up a particular macro, it leads me to that particular header file where it is defined. So I want to know how to set include paths, because there are many include directories in many folders.

Comment: make TAGS (Emacs) or make tags(vim), use M-. in Emacs (don't know in Vim) and give it the TAGS file and it finds the definitions for you. It's much faster than eclipse. And personally if you're going to learn gcc and you're trying to do some from eclipse then you're doing it wrong but thats just me :P

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer. Just add the include paths to the C/C++ Include paths in Project/Properties in Eclipse. Then right click Project-> Index -> Rebuild. The indexer of eclipse ran for around 20 mins. It built the index for the project. And now I am able to navigate the project efficiently. And even the "Symbol could not be resolved" errors disappeared.